Is it possible to respect the aspect ratio of a responsive image with an initial width and height
Let's say that I have an HTML image with predefined, hard-coded and immutable width and height values:
<img src="img.png" style="width: 800px; height: 600px" />

And a CSS rule to make all images responsive:
img {
  max-width: 100%
}

The problem is that when the page is resized, the image's aspect ratio is not preserved.
Is it possible to keep the aspect ratio, given that:

I can't change the inline style for the image
But I can change the global CSS

Note: The solution has to be generic as width: 800px; height: 600px is just a sample and the ratio could be anything.

I usually don't set height. Try the simplest way with 'aspect ratio' instead.

img {height: auto!important} ?

@TemaniAfif using !important is in almost every case wrong.

You can try with object-fit

@t.niese !important is a CSS feature that can be used if needed. Assuming that all the usage of !important are wrong, is actually wrong.

@TemaniAfif I didn't say that it is wrong in any case. I said in most of the cases. I at least would mention that the scope of the selector should as specific as possible if there is really no way around it.

And you have absolutly no control over the html created?

@t.niese he is using inline styles, so only important can be more specific than inline styles

@TemaniAfif Sure, but when using!important I would limit the selector to not just be img, but to ideally only target the img elements that should have that behavior.

@t.niese I do not have any control over the HTML created and can only rely of custom CSS

can you give more html context ? whats arround the img and does it have a width too ?

If the inline styles are actually the intrinsic width and height of the image then all you have to do is to reset the height to auto. You can keep the width as it is since you have max-width.


img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto!important
}
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/800/600" style="width: 800px; height: 600px" >




Unfortunately, width and height could be anything, even a wrong aspect ratio for that image.

@jonjbar which make this solution even better because it will reset the image to its "correct" aspect-ratio

What you need is for the width and height to be relative to the same figure.
For example:


img {
      max-width: 100%;
      width: 100vw  !important;/*Define the size according to the ratio of the image*/
      height: 120vw  !important;
    }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="https://pickture.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/%D7%A8%D7%A7%D7%A2-%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%94-%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%9D-32-768x768.jpg">
</body>
</html>



In this example, the width and height will be relative to the width of the page.
(the !important is to override the height and width defined in html)
